# Much faster interpolation in Python?

Tags: python, performance, scipy, interpolation

I am looking for a very fast interpolation in Python. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import time
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input="-0.5 0.0 \
-0.4 0.6 \
-0.3 0.9    \
-0.2 0.85 \
-0.1 0.82 \
0.0 0.8 \
0.1 0.7 \
0.2 0.6 \
0.3 0.4 \
0.4 0.3 \
0.5 0.02"

start_time = time.time()

input_coordinates = np.genfromtxt(input.splitlines()).reshape(-1,2) # shape to 2 columns, any number of rows
x_coordinates = input_coordinates[:,0]
H_values = input_coordinates[:,1]
H_interpolation = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x_coordinates, H_values)
# H_interpolation = interp1d(x_coordinates, H_values)
# H_interpolation = interp1d(x_coordinates, H_values, kind='cubic')

def function(x):
    return H_interpolation(x)*np.exp(2/np.sqrt(1+x))

complex_integral = quad(function, -0.5, 0.5)

print("Quad",complex_integral)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

xnew = np.arange(-0.5, 0.5, 0.01)
ynew = H_interpolation(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
plt.plot(x_coordinates, H_values, '.', label='original data')
plt.plot(xnew, ynew, '-', label='interpolation')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Where for:

```
interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
```

time is 0.011002779006958008 seconds
and for:

```
interp1d type linear
```

time is 0.05301189422607422 seconds
and for:

```
interp1d type cubic
```

time is 0.03500699996948242 seconds.

But I am looking for something really much faster due to multiple calculations in huge loops. Is there any much faster function approximation in Python? It should be accurate too.

I observed that if I reduce number of input points in

```
input
```

the time of calculation also drops, but I don't have much possibilities for reducing the number of points in input data.

Comment: I notice your time measurements include the time spent in print() functions as well as the time spent calling quad() on your results, so you might not be getting accurate timing on the interpolation calls.

Comment: So you are using the interpolation within the `quad`.  That will be calling the interpolation many times (at least 21?) with one value at time.  You might want to explore other integration methods, seeking one that would let you call the interpolation few times, but with many points each time.  That could be faster.

Comment: You are true @hpaulj . Do you have any idea how not to call `H_interpolation(x)` such many times? When I print in the `def function(x)`, the `H_interpolation(x)` part of equation is responsible for additional calculations, probably non-necessary.

Comment: The problem is that scipy.integrate.quad calls function several hundred times. The simplest solution is to use something which can be vectorized. eg. `ynew = function(xnew);simps(ynew,xnew)` This is much faster, but depending on the inputs less accurate. Another possibility which is also a lot faster and gives the same results is to implement a low level callable. But this is more work to do (wrapping/reimplementing the fortran code which evaluates the spline and creating a low-level callable which you can pass to scipy.integrate.quad.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of your interpolation depends almost entirely upon the complexity of your approximation function.  What mathematical properties can you guarantee about the your input points and the desired output?  You need to take full advantage of those to improve over the general-purpose methods you're using.

Most important, remember that virtually all CPUs now implement on-chip transcendental functions: basic trig functions, exp, sqrt, log, etc.  These are micro-coded for blinding speed, such that `sin(x)` or `exp(x)` is faster than a fifth-degree polynomial in `x` (five multiplications, five additions).

You should also explore using vectorized operations, to handle a set of interpolations in parallel.

Comment: interp1d has quite a bit of overhead actually

Comment: How can I vectorize my calculations? Use pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes.  PANDAS and NumPy both incorporate vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use interp1d if you care about performance. Use interpolators directly:

- for linear interpolation, use np.interp (yes, numpy)
- for cubic use either CubicSpline or make_interp_spline

Note that the latter objects allow vectorized evaluations, so you might avoid python looping altogether.

Also note that scipy interpolators have e.g. .integrate method, so you might avoid using quad, too.

Comment: How should I interpolate using np.interp outside of `def function(x):` ? I would like to avoid multiple calculations of interpolation. With: 
`def function(x):
    res=np.interp(x, x_coordinates, H_values)
    return np.exp(1j*2/np.sqrt(1+x))*res`
timing is 0.314 seconds. With 
`def function(x):
    res=H_interpolation(x)
    return np.exp(1j*2/np.sqrt(1+x))*res` time is 0.15s.

Comment: Ok, maybe you've found a case where interp1d is faster then np. interp